# no audio devices available when i make dial from SF using chrome extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, dom-manipulation, amazon-chime

i have created amazon chime audio inside the chrome extension  and clicking call icon from Salesforce domain and that action will open the extension and make a dial that time microphone and speakers are not available from amazon chime. but initially it was there  why  audio devices not available from amazon chime while making dial from salesforce

i have given allow micro phone permission to my iframe and added permisssion to manifest.json. but making dial From Salesforce no audio device found is showing inside the amazon chime audio devices dropdwon. i want to list the audio devices while making dial from SF.